# ¿Cómo evitar valores duplicados?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo dos tablas: *empleados* y *faltas*.

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *empleados* son los siguientes:

| id | num_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | Juan |
| 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 03 | 1120 | María |
| 04 | 1121 | José |
| 05 | 1134 | Meli |

La estructura y datos de ejemplo para la tabla *faltas* son los siguientes:

| id | num_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 01/08/21 |
| 02 | 1104 | 03/08/21 |
| 03 | 1104 | 04/08/21 |
| 04 | 1104 | 05/08/21 |

Estoy generando la siguiente consulta SQL para enlistar las coincidencias en la columna *num_empleado*:

`SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN faltas ON usuarios.num_empleado = faltas.num_empleado`

Y se me despliega un resultado como el siguiente:

| id | num_empleado | fecha | id | num_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 01/08/21 | 01 | 1100 | Juan |
| 02 | 1104 | 03/08/21 | 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 03 | 1104 | 04/08/21 | 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 04 | 1104 | 05/08/21 | 02 | 1104 | Luis |

Lo que busco obtener es algo así:

| id | num_empleado | id | num_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1100 | 01 | 1100 | Juan |
| 02 | 1104 | 02 | 1104 | Luis |

Sólo busco que me muestre las coincidencias en la columna *num_empleado* una sola vez. Si existe coincidencia entre ambas tablas en esa columna, que me las despliegue una sola vez (sin importar que en la tabla *faltas* se muestre en varias ocasiones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecciona solo los campos que quieres mostrar y agrupa el resultado por esos campos

```
    SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.num_empleado, usuarios.nombre 
    FROM usuarios 
    INNER JOIN faltas ON usuarios.no_empleado = faltas.no_empleado
    group by usuarios.id, usuarios.num_empleado, usuarios.nombre
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no estaba familiarizado con cómo aplicar GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo único que quieres es obtener los empleados con faltas, es mejor verificar la existencia en vez de unir por completo las tablas.

```
SELECT *
FROM `Empleados` AS e
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
               FROM `Faltas` AS f
               WHERE e.`num_empleado` = f.`num_empleado`);
```